# Javascript visualization: acceptable size of svg map?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, visualization, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a map from an svg file using Raphael.js. My problem is that the original map is quite detailed. I think I have to reduce the number of points in Illustrator, but I'm not sure how far I have to push it.

What would you, roughly, say is an acceptable size of the svg file? The idea is to add some interacitvity to the map once I extracted the paths and visualized them using Raphael.js.

At the moment the file, which holds about 300 polygons an 17.000 points, is about 180 kb.

-jens

Comment: What is "acceptable" is fairly arbitrary.

Comment: You can use localStorage to cache the data if it's not expected to change much, see e.g http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-super-efficient-svg-characters-localstorage.

Comment: Thanks Erik. That is a very interesting feature that I didn't know about. My experience from other detailed svgs is that they tend to become quite heavy on older computers and browsers when you start to add interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your webserver to compress what it serves (deflate is the most common algorithm) then the file will be compressed as a matter of course, and SVG files compress readily thanks to the repetition of the data structure.

If it's still too big, consider what the purpose of the illustration is; does it need to be that detailed?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem recently, but it was letterforms instead of a map. If you take a look at the source code of the SVG it will look something like...

```
M 0 0 L 1.29384945877 28.494585495 L 1.29384945877 28.494585495 ...
```

All those extra digits are preciseness you don't need, you can get away with one or two decimals and it will look exactly the same. I removed them and achieved 60-70% compression.

You can remove them with a regex replace.

Comment: Thanks Duopixel, such a clever and easy solution!